# Formulating maximum likelihood estimation as a conditional probability

Tags: maximum-likelihood, notation

In explaining MLE, some texts (such as [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/191)) formulate the likelihood function as:
$\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i; \theta)$

while some texts (such as [this](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/courses/s200/lectures/lect11.pdf)) formulale the likelihood function  as:
$\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i| \theta)$

The basic difference is that, in the latter, $f$ is given as a conditional probability. Do they mean the same thing? What are their differences?

Answer (score 5):

This is merely a matter of convention for denoting the dependence of the density on the unknown parameter. This dependence becomes a probabilistic dependence on the random variable $\theta$ only when $\theta$ itself is a random variable, namely in the Bayesian setting.