# What is the meaning of $p(y|x;\theta)$ and $p(x;\theta)$ and $p(x,y|z)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, notation

I saw these in a machine learning notes. and like to know the meaning of them? also the formula of them?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30825/13680) might be helpful.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244403/36229)

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SO! They are simply a notation for conditional probabilities. You often see them in Bayesian statistics.

How to interpret it:

For instance, your example $p(y|x;\theta)$ means what is the probability that you observe $y$, when $x$ and $\theta$ 'holds'. Usually, $x$ stands for some data and $\theta$ parameters of distribution, or a model. It can be the probability of observing something given the dataset $x$ and estimated linear regression coefficients $\theta = (\beta_0,\beta_1)$.

Have a look for instance at [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't say about p(x;y) , p(x|y,z) and p(x|y;z)

Comment: that is just the notation of conditional probability, if not stated otherwise

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.